# Omnivorous fusion and Earth at war with distant colonies

Tags: story-identification, space, warfare

I recall reading a novel, probably back in the 1990's, that featured the use of omnivorous fusion reactions used for weapons and propulsion, and Earth being at war with distant colonies that occasionally sent ships to attack.

The main characters were asteroid miners, and it featured interesting descriptions of the mining process and a good scientific explanation of omnivorous fusion.

Can someone remember what this book was called?

Comment: Do you remember any more details? Language, country, cover art, short novel or long? There are [LOTS](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=node%3D25&field-keywords=Asteroid+miners) of [asteroid miners](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/AsteroidMiners). And their vehicles are often powered by fusion (perhaps less frequently than fission, but many times more often than PV solar or [steam](http://www.amazon.com/dp/0812541731)).

Comment: They felt very lucky to get real beef. The omnivorous fusion was more exotic than what they generally used for asteroid mining. That was probably regular hydrogen fusion, or something even more mundane. It seems like they would stop the asteroid from spinning, survey and tag it, and shoot it to a giant net located near Jupiter. English was the language.

Answer (score 3):

Is it possibly the Asteroid War series by Ben Bova?   In it, there is widespread use of fusion energy generators to aid with propulsion and asteroid mining.  The first volume of the series came out in 2001 and if you were thinking late 1990s when you read it, it would be around the right time.

[Wiki Asteroid Wars - volume 1 - The Precipice](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Precipice)

Comment: Good answer, but the story I read did not feature the owners of the asteroid mining operations, but the miners themselves.